# How do I access all the pixels for a Raster Source

Tags: openlayers-6

I am attempting to calculate some statistics for pixel values using openlayers 6.3.1 & I am having an issue iterating over all pixels. I have read the docs for the pixels array that gets passed to the operation callback and it states:

> For `pixel` type operations, the function will be called with an array
> of  * pixels, where each pixel is an array of four numbers (`[r, g, b, a]`) in the  * range of 0 - 255. It should return a single pixel
> array.

I have taken this to mean that the array passed contains all the pixels but everything I do seems to prove that I only get the current pixel to work on.

```
if(this.rasterSource == null) {
            this.rasterSource = new Raster({
                sources: [this.imageLayer],
                operation: function (pixels, data) {      
                    data['originalPixels'] = pixels;              
                    if(!isSetUp) {
                        // originalPixels = pixels as number[][];
                        // const originalPixels = Array.from(pixels as number[][]);
                       
                        // let originals = generateOriginalHistograms(pixels as number[][]);
                        isSetUp = true;
                    }    

                    // console.log(pixels[0]);
                    let pixel = pixels[0];
                    pixel[data['channel']] = data['value'];
                    return pixel;
                },
                lib: {
                    isSetUp: isSetUp,
                    numBins: numBins,
                    // originalPixels: originalPixels,
                    // originalRed: originalRed,
                    // originalGreen: originalGreen,
                    // originalBlue: originalBlue,
                    generateOriginalHistograms: generateOriginalHistograms,
                }
            });


this.rasterSource.on('beforeoperations', function(event) {
            event.data.channel = 0;
            event.data.value = 255;  
        });

        this.rasterSource.on('afteroperations', function(event) {
            console.debug("After Operations");
        });
```

I have realised that I cannot pass arrays through the lib object so I have had to stop attempting that. These are the declarations I am currently using:

```
const numBins = 256;
var isSetUp: boolean = false;
    
function generateOriginalHistograms(pixels: number[][]) {
    let originalRed = new Array(numBins).fill(0);
    let originalGreen = new Array(numBins).fill(0);
    let originalBlue = new Array(numBins).fill(0);

    for(let i = 0; i < numBins; ++i) {
        originalRed[Math.floor(pixels[i][0])]++
        originalGreen[Math.floor(pixels[i][1])]++;
        originalBlue[Math.floor(pixels[i][2])]++;
    }

    return {red: originalRed, blue: originalBlue, green: originalGreen};
```

}

& they are declared outside of the current angular component that I am writing this in. I did have another question on this but I have since realised that I was way off in what I could and couldn't use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755943/openlayers-rastersource-operation-callback-cant-find-objects-function);

This now runs and, as it is currently commented will tint the image red. But the value of `data['originalPixels'] = pixels;` only ever produces one pixel. Can anyone tell me why this is & what I need to do to access the whole pixel array. I have tried to slice & spread the array to no avail. If I uncomment the line `// let originals = generateOriginalHistograms(pixels as number[][]);` I get an error ​

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
generateOriginalHistograms @ blob:http://localhos…a7fa-b5a410582c06:6
(anonymous) @ blob:http://localhos…7fa-b5a410582c06:76
(anonymous) @ blob:http://localhos…7fa-b5a410582c06:62
(anonymous) @ blob:http://localhos…7fa-b5a410582c06:83
```

& if I uncomment the line `// console.log(pixels[0]);` I get all the pixel values streaming in the console but quite slowly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be change the operationType to 'image' and work with the ImageData object.

```
this.rasterSource = new Raster({
     sources: [this.imageLayer],
     operationType: "image",
     operation: function (pixels, data) {   
        let imageData = pixels[0] as ImageData;
        ...
```

I now have no issues calculating the stats I need.